# GWT & Eclipse: UiBinder - Field has no corresponding field in template file

Tags: eclipse, gwt, field, uibinder

With the following:

```java
public class PromotionTableComposite<T extends Promotion> extends Composite {

    @UiField(provided=true)
    protected CellTable<T> displayTable;

    @UiField(provided=true)
    protected SimplePager pager;
```

And

```xml
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder
  xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
  xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
  xmlns:c="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client">

  <g:DockLayoutPanel
    unit="EM">
    <!-- DataGrid. -->
    <g:center>
      <c:CellTable
        ui:field='displayTable'/>
    </g:center>

    <!-- Pager. -->
    <g:south
      size="3">
      <g:HTMLPanel>
        <table
          style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td
              align='center'>
              <c:SimplePager
                ui:field='pager'/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:south>
  </g:DockLayoutPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Eclipse gives me the errors:

"Field displayTable has no corresponding field in the template file PromotionTableComposite.ui.xml"

"Field pager has no corresponding field in the template file PromotionTableComposite.ui.xml".

And when I run the project I get the following runtime error:

java.lang.AssertionError: UiField pager with 'provided = true' was null

What have I done wrong? I have checked the build properties so that it includes all source files and excludes non (so that the ui.xml file is included alongside the java file).

Comment: Can you please show your PromotionTableComposite.java file ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that in your constructor you didn't initialize `displayTable` and `pager` before `initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));`.

```java
private static PromotionTableCompositeUiBinder uiBinder = 
                             GWT.create(PromotionTableCompositeUiBinder.class);

@UiField(provided=true)
CellTable<T> displayTable;

@UiField(provided=true)
SimplePager pager;    

public PromotionTableComposite(){

    this.displayTable = new CellTable<T>();
    this.pager = new SimplePager();

    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

    ...

}
```